# Google Cloud Functions deploy error: Changed virtual-env and deploy still referencing old virtual environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I switched to a new virtual environment for my google cloud functions development, and now when I try to execute `gcloud functions deploy {function name} --runtime python37 --source=. --trigger-http` (with or without `--source` tag), I get the following error that references my old virtual environment directory instead of the new one:

`ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) Error building source archive from path [.]. Could not validate source files: [[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '{**OLD VIRTUAL ENV DIRECTORY**}/python3']. Please ensure that path [.] contains function code or specify another directory with --source`

However, adding `--source=.` doesn't fix the error.

My new virtual env is activated and I'm deploying from within the same directory as my source files, etc. `gcloud` seems to remember my old virtual-env and I'm not sure how to tell it that I'm working from a new one now. Any tips much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Deactivate your virtual environment or use a different shell or command prompt. Google Cloud does not need your virtual environment. Dependencies are specified in the requirements.txt file. Your virtual environment can interfere with the CLI tools.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those solved the issue. The error message persists.

Comment: Have you tried using a fresh shell / command prompt? The error message should have changed.

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore` file or `.gcloudignore` file? If so, could you share them with us? If you can also share your project folder structure, at least the root directory, where you run your `gcloud` command will be great.

Comment: Okay for some reason it didn't like the presence of the old virtual environment directory. By removing that directory deploy is no longer complaining and I can deploy successfully. Can anyone tell me why gcloud didn't like the old venv directory hanging around (even if I renamed it to something random)? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comment thread, removing the old virtual environment directory solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A more appropriate solution than removing your local `venv` directory would be to add the `venv` folder to your `.gcloudignore` (create it if you haven't) file.

I faced the same issue as you, which brought me here, but rather than delete my venv folder (I still need it), I created a `.gcloudignore` file and added `venv` to it. It worked.